# Error installing flask-sqlalchemy "Could not build wheels for greenlet..."

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, greenlets

New to Flask, trying to install Flask-SQLAlchemy "pip install flask Flask-SQLAlchemy".  Getting error building wheel for `greenlet`:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
```

I tried installing `greenlet` via `pip` but that fails with the same error.  This is in Windows 10 and VSCode.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to upgrade `pip` and `setoptools` here is the command `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ankit.  After updating setoptools (I had already updated pip)  it is still failing with the same error.

Comment: ** I didn't notice this before but I am seeing this error now:  "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools"".  I did install the build tools but even after that I am still seeing this error.